# Instagram-embed not showing due to height being 0px

Tags: javascript, reactjs, instagram

Currently I'm using typescript along with react 17.0.2. I made a yarn add react-instagram-embed. I have a component called instagram.tsx where I'm using the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import InstagramEmbed from "react-instagram-embed";

export default function Instagram({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div >
      <InstagramEmbed
        url="https://instagr.am/p/Zw9o4/"
        maxWidth={600}
        hideCaption={false}
        containerTagName="div"
        protocol=""
        injectScript
        onLoading={() => {}}
        onSuccess={() => {}}
        onAfterRender={() => {}}
        onFailure={() => {}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I go to my webpage I cannot see the instagram post. I went to inspect element to check out the react developer tools and I could see the correct components:
[image]

But when I hover over the components I get
[image]

I have tried adding height manually by adding style={{height:"400px"}} in the parent component and maxHeight in the instagramEmbed component but it still does not show up

Comment: Can't see `clientAccessToken` prop, it's marked as required in the [docs](https://github.com/sugarshin/react-instagram-embed#props). Are you sure that the post you are trying to display using this component really loads? See the Network tab to check if your component sends the request to Instagram API.

Comment: I have tried adding the clientAccessToken="123|456" but it still dint work. And Im getting this in my console index.js:71 GET https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/instagram_oembed/?url=https%3A%2F%2Finstagr.am%2Fp%2FZw9o4%2F&hidecaption=false&omitscript=true&fields=html&maxwidth=320 401